# VSCode - IntelliSense with custom languages

Tags: tokenize, visual-studio-code, extending

Hello VS Code Community!

I'm currently extending the VS Code editor with a own / custom language. This is easier as I thought but now I'm getting problems with IntelliSense.

[image]

---

As you can see, VS Code is suggesting me the content of comments and strings and that's the big problem for me.

I'm inexperienced to this and learning by trying ;) I guess it has to do with tokenizer but I have no idea how to specify / exclude comments and variable values.

Normally only declared variables and the given keywords should be suggested

Here the relevant code: (only for learning purposes, no copyright infringement intended)

```html
/*---------------------------------------------------------
 * Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *--------------------------------------------------------*/
/// <reference path="../../declares.d.ts" />
'use strict';
define(["require", "exports", '../sqfDef', 'monaco-testing'], function (require, exports, languageDef, T) {
    var tokenizationSupport = T.createTokenizationSupport(languageDef.language);
    var tokenize = T.createTokenizeFromSupport(tokenizationSupport);
    var assertTokens = T.assertTokens;
    T.module('Syntax Highlighting - SQF');
}
```

Are there any docs or can someone explain me please how to exclude this from the suggested list?

EDIT:
Ok, I realised that you can define object types in the Def.js so defining them in the Tests.js is not necessary. yet my problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is currently no documentation for writing custom plugins we all gather our information by reverse engineering.

Take a look at `resources\app\plugins\vs.language.typescript\features\suggestSupport.js`. In line 10 you find this `this.excludeTokens = ['string', 'comment', 'numeric'];`. 
So you need to write your own `suggestSupport.js` and register it in your `languageMain.js`.

You find an example setting it up in `resources\app\plugins\vs.language.typescript\typescriptMain.js` in line 58:

```
    var suggestSupport = new SuggestSupport(ctx, client);
    monaco.Modes.SuggestSupport.register(MODE_ID, suggestSupport);
    return Configuration.load(MODE_ID, ctx.configurationService).then(function (config) {
        suggestSupport.setConfiguration(config);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I should've used vs.language,typescript as template from the very beginning instead of .csharp ^.^ it has much more things described.